# Merge select from two postgresql tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count

I have two tables users and followers in result i need to get quantity of following of users and quantity of followers:

users:

```
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | a
  7 | b
  2 | c
  3 | d
  4 | e
  5 | f
  6 | g
```

followers:

```
 fid | uid 
-----+-----
   1 |   7
   1 |   2
   1 |   6
   1 |   3
   7 |   1
```

I trying to do:

```
SELECT id, name, count(fid) as following, count(uid) as followers 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN followers on users.id=followers.fid 
group by id;
```

and getting wrong result:

```
 id | name | following | followers 
----+------+-----------+-----------
  1 |   a  |         4 |         4
  7 |   b  |         1 |         1
```

P.S. i'm newbie in clean sql syntax, please to fix my query.

Comment: Looks like you need a second join on id = uid for the followers count.

Comment: Example please.

Comment: `SELECT id, name, count(fing.fid) as following, count(fers.uid) as followers 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN followers fing on u.id=fing.fid 
INNER JOIN followers fers on u.id=fers.uid
group by u.id;`

Comment: i did something similar before and was getting wrong result. Your sample returns   1 | a | 8 |  8

Comment: @otoshavadze has a good answer below. I'm not fluent in postgres syntax so I'm not 100% confident giving you a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need something like this:

```
select users.*, t1.following, t2.followers from users
left join (select fid, count(*) as following from followers group by fid) t1
on users.id = t1.fid
left join (select uid, count(*) as followers from followers group by uid) t2
on users.id = t2.uid
-- where following is not null or  followers is not null
```

If you need exclude users, who not are followings and not have followers, then uncomment last `WHERE` line

Comment: Thank you, this is what i need.